# NodeJS cPanel Hosting

Tags: node.js, server, hosting, cpanel

I set up a NodeJS API on cPanel using the NodeJS setup that is provided. the app starts but none of my endpoints are reachable with 404 pages being displayed.

In the cPanel > metrics > errors I can see the error: Path for NodeJS application is invalid: /home/username/repositories/repo

where username is the cpanel username and repo is the server.

I used the built in git support in cPanel to link to a remote repo via SSH. This part is most likely not the problem since I can see the actual server files referenced in the NodeJS server with the correct path (which is why this error message is so strange.)

The server works fine on localhost so this likely has something to do with cPanel.

I have never hosted a node app on cPanel and I know a VPS would be better but this is what I have to work with for now. There isn't a lot of discussions/forums/docs on this online so I am running out of options.

I would highly appreciate it if someone can tell me what is wrong or guide me in the right direction for where to start looking for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. When you don't use a git repo you can use a relative path from your home to the place the server is stored. i.e. don't include home/username/ in the path

for git repos you must use the absolute path meaning
home/username/repositories/yourserver

where "username" is your cPanel username and "yourserver" is the name of the folder where your server is located